# linux - error while trying to install mcrypt extension centos 7

Tags: linux, php-mcrypt

i tried to install mcrypt extension for centos 7 (64bit)
I'm going nuts, and can't seem to fix the problem, can anybody guide me what's wrong with this or tell me the specific command to fix the problem?

```
[root@hawk-enive-ee ~]# sudo yum install php-mcrypt
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.hosteurope.de
 * epel: mirror.de.leaseweb.net
 * extras: ftp.plusline.de
 * updates: mirror.de.leaseweb.net
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-mcrypt.x86_64 0:5.4.16-5.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64 for package: php-mcrypt-5.4.16-5.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php(api) = 20100412-64 for package: php-mcrypt-5.4.16-5.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.4.16-36.3.el7_2 will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: php70w-common-7.0.12-1.w7.x86_64 conflicts php-common < 7.0
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: php70w-common conflicts with php-common-5.4.16-36.3.el7_2.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
```

Answer (score 1):

Your base PHP install appears to be from from Webtatic. The corresponding `mcrypt` package is called `php70w-mcrypt`:

```
yum install php70w-mcrypt
```